# how to show distinct attribute value in a ComboBox using LINQ?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, dynamic-linq

this is the Book class
**Book{BookId, Title, Category, Quantity};**
So, how would i select only one object from each category using linq query?
i tryed like this,

```
this.catagoryList.DataContext = ldc.Books.Distinct(); //categoryList is a ComboBox
```

but you know it doesn't work. All of these objects are unique, so it shows same category for many time. 
Actually i want it like GroupBy, but i would like to select only one objects from each group to show unique categories in the ComboBox. Thanks.

XAML:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CatagoryTemplate">
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Catagory}"/>
          </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
...
 <ComboBox Name="catagoryList" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CatagoryTemplate}" SelectionChanged="catagoryList_SelectionChanged" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this.catagoryList.DataContext = ldc.Books.Select(b => b.Category).Distinct();
```

If you don't want to change your template:

```
catagoryList.DataContext = ldc.Books.Select(b => b.Category)
                                    .Distinct()
                                    .Select(c => new { Catagory = c });
```

But I think it's better to change template to match strings.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CatagoryTemplate">
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
      </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object!! please see the XAML Code

Comment: You have misprint `Catagory`. Also you are trying to bind to property `Catagory`, but this linq returns list of strings.

Comment: your suggestion is really helpful, but its not working. is there any different way?

Comment: May be an exceptions : "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Answer (score 2):

While context of this code isn't clear, in general, you should probably leave the ComboBox's DataContext alone and bind its ItemsSource property to a property in your view model that returns your linq query.

That said, in your specific code, you just have to Select() the Category before you call Distinct():

> this.catagoryList.DataContext = ldc.Books.Select(book=>book.Category).Distinct();

EDIT:

Just remove your DataTemplate, it is not useful.  If you set your DataContext to the LINQ query above and then bind ItemsSource to the DataContext as you are doing, it will display the list of strings properly.

Comment: exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object!!
please see the XAML Code.

Answer (score 1):

```
ldb.Books.Select(b=>b.Category).Distinct()
```